# How can I restrict access to my PHP elastic beanstalk environment by IP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently moved a test PHP site that I was hosting locally onto AWS servers.

Before, I was restricting access to my site via a .htaccess file, although this doesn't seem to be working since moving to elastic beanstalk.

What's the best way to restrict access to my site to only a specified range of IPs?

Comment: Why not try and figure out why .htaccess is not working instead? It could be a simple as enabling .htaccess in the Apache config with `AllowOverride All`. There is nothing different about how apache works locally and on a cloud server. But there are somethings that aren't turned on by default in some Apache distros and .htacesss on 2.4 is one of them.

Comment: @PanamaJack The reason is almost certainly because the Apache servers are sitting behind a load balancer and the OP didn't configure it to check the `x-forwarded-for` header to get the user's real IP.

Comment: @MarkB yes if it's behind a LB that does make sense because it will always see the LB ip. He can easily adjust his rules to look for x-forwarded -for but he did not post them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a pretty good firewall that sits in front of the EC2 instances. That would be where I would restrict access by IP.

AWS calls them [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

> A security group acts as a virtual firewall that controls the traffic for one or more instances. When you launch an instance, you associate one or more security groups with the instance. You add rules to each security group that allow traffic to or from its associated instances. You can modify the rules for a security group at any time; the new rules are automatically applied to all instances that are associated with the security group. When we decide whether to allow traffic to reach an instance, we evaluate all the rules from all the security groups that are associated with the instance.

Comment: I've tried this way, but restricting the inbound seems to kill the health of my instance

Comment: @Luke4792 You need to modify the Security Group attached to the Elastic Load Balancer, not the SG attached to the EC2 instances. The SG attached to the EC2 instances should have one rule, allowing inbound access from the SG attached to the ELB.

Comment: Whereabouts would I find the option that allows me to change the elastic load balancer SG on an already deployed instance?

Comment: Your ELB **AND** EC2 instances will have to have a SG added to them. You do not need to restart either to make changes.